# Hi, I'm working on a Electronic Raffle Draw project

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a ELECTRONIC RAFFLE DRAW project using VISUAL STUDIO 2010. I have a list of name in my sql database, and displayed it to a listview, along with certain conditions on what names should be displayed. Now, what I want to do is randomly select names from this list view. And I'm trying to convert this items from listview and convert it to a string array. I also have timer where when it's `enable=true` it should display these string array to a label.

And when ticker is `enable=false`. It should stop and display one specific name. All my codes are working except I get an `InvalidCastException` was `unhandled` in this specific line of code

```
ReDim strng(Name_ListView.Items.Count - 1)
            Name_ListView.Items.CopyTo(strng, 0)

Dim strng() As String

Private Sub Frm_Raffle_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            ReDim strng(Name_ListView.Items.Count - 1)
            Name_ListView.Items.CopyTo(strng, 0)
    End Sub

Public Sub myTimer_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles myTimer.Tick
        Dim index As Integer = rnd.Next(Name_ListView.Items.Count)
        mylblResult.Text = strng(index)
    End Sub
```

Comment: How could you hope to copy a list of `ListViewItem` objects to a `String` array?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I hoping to maybe get any other option than the things I've done so far.

Comment: If anyone can suggest any other option for the program to successfully run. it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: If what you actually want is the text displayed in each `ListViewItem` then that is what you should be getting, not the `ListViewItem` objects themselves.  No, I won't be explaining how to do that.  That's the sort of thing that you need to research.  If you want to use a `ListView` then you need to learn the basics of using a `ListView`.  Getting text in and out is very much the basics.

Comment: By the way, what's with the VBA tag on the question?  The description for that tag EXPLICITLY states that VBA is not equivalent to VB.NET.  Only add relevant tags.

Comment: There's also nothing to do with MySQL in there so I removed that tag too.  Just because you are using MySQL in the project does not mean that it is relevant to this question.

Comment: New here. Sorry. Don't know the rules yet.